# const string discards qualifiers

Tags: c++

I have some code:

```
const string MY_STRINGS[3] = { "A", "B", "C" };
```

and when I try to do this:

```
int main() {
  MY_STRINGS[1] = MY_STRINGS[2];
}
```

I get the following error:

> Passing 'const std::string' as 'this' argument of 'std::basic_string... & std::basic_string::operator= ...' discards qualifiers.

Sure.  Makes sense.  I can't assign to a `const string`.

But when I do the following:

```
int main() {
  const string SOME_STRINGS[3] = MY_STRINGS;
  MY_STRINGS[1] = MY_STRINGS[2];
}
```

this compiles and works.  What has changed, and why does it now compile?

Comment: This fails to compile on VS2010 (had to change initialisation of `SOME_STRINGS` to `SOME_STRINGS[3] = { MY_STRINGS[0], ... };`. What compiler are you using? Can you post a single block of code that causes this?

Comment: @hmjd: I've confirmed this behaviour with GCC 4.3.4: http://ideone.com/qWNjy.

Comment: @hmjd that is indeed what I meant (though I have SOME_STRINGS[3]?).  And yes, I'm compiling on GCC 4.2.1.

Comment: @alexc, no I didn't change `SOME_STRINGS` at all: just stating that I had to use initializer braces for VS2010 to compile it. Anyway, it is not really relevant to your actual question (I was concerned it was not the actual code posted but it has been reproduced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe GCC copies the array. Thus ensuring the const array is immutable and the variable array mutable.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string varStrs[] = {"unchanged", "changed"};
    const string constStrs[2] = varStrs;

    varStrs[0] = varStrs[1];
    //constStrs[0] = constStrs[1]; // <-- will not compile

    cout << "const str: " << constStrs[0] << endl;
    cout << "var str: " << varStrs[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I tested this on GCC version 4.1.2

Comment: Odd, but this does seem to be GCC's behavior for somewhere from about 4.1.* to 4.4.*.

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid naming your identifiers with ALL_CAPS.

Second, I really do not believe your second code snippet would actually compile.

Try this in your compiler and if this compiles as well, your compiler is broken:

```
int main()
{
   int foo[3] = {1, 2, 3};
   int bar[3] = foo; // Should fail to compile here.
}
```

Comment: The second code snippet does indeed compile, at least in GCC 4.1.2 and 4.3.4, with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It doesn't in 4.6.1.

Comment: I suspect you come from the google school kMyStrings.  I'm not attached to either one, nor is this code actually for anything -- I'm just curious why it works in one case and not the other.  Additionally, the line you suggested won't compile, but that's simply because you haven't declared them const (which should set them to point to the same memory, rather than allocating different arrays on the stack).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley are you trying Happy Green Kid's code or mine?  As suggested, the const is important.

Comment: @alex c: I can't try your code, it's not complete.  I am using the code that Oli provided in the link in his comment on your question.  This one: http://ideone.com/qWNjy

Comment: @alexc: With the flags that Oli specified, both lines in main break the build.  This one: `MY_STRINGS[1] = MY_STRINGS[2];` is an actual error.  The other one only is a warning due to unused variable `SOME_STRINGS`. But with `-Werror`, that breaks the build.

Comment: @alexc: One other thing.  Your assessment of why Happy's code should not compile is incorrect.  The const should not affect it.  Setting them to const does not set them to point to the same memory. Though theoretically it could, that would be an optimization technique and does not change the fact that it is incorrect C++ to assign an array like that, const or otherwise.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Sure; I'm just noting what happens in my version of gcc; one compiles, one does not, and that's what is happening.  But you're absolutely right that both should not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler bug.

First, `const string SOME_STRINGS[3] = MY_STRINGS;` is not legal C++. It must be a GCC extension or something to allow arrays to be copy-initialised.

Second, this extension seems to break detection of even the most basic type-safety violation (assiging to a `const`). This is worrying.